# unquote-splice within quote causes symbol-not-found error

Tags: clojure, macros

Here is the code:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-form [& args]
  {:form (quote `(inspect-caller-form ~@args))})
(inspect-caller-form 1 2 3)
```

and the error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: args in this context, compiling:(/Users/kaiyin/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/cina/src/cina/ref_types.clj:406:5)
```

But if I move the syntax-quote before `quote`, things seems to work:

```
(defmacro inspect-caller-form [& args]
  {:form `(quote (inspect-caller-form ~@args))})
(inspect-caller-form 1 2 3)
```

why?

Answer (score 2):

It can often help debugging syntax-quoting problems by simply evaluating them at the repl and seeing what form they evaluate to. In this case we can see that the first example expands to the unevaluated result of reading the syntax quote. This is because syntax quote is one of the few reader macros in clojure and gets to do it's work at the start of macro expansion time. Then your call to quote prevents it from being expanded further. So syntax-quote never gets to finish it's work.

```
user> (let [args [1 2 3]]
        (quote `(inspect-caller-form ~@args)))

(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat 
                      (clojure.core/list 
                          (quote user/inspect-caller-form)) 
                      args))
```

While the second one allows the syntax quote form to finish evaluation, and produce as its result a call to quote. So the final result is a single quoted list with the values already spliced into it.

```
user> (let [args [1 2 3]]
        `(quote (inspect-caller-form ~@args)))

(quote (user/inspect-caller-form 1 2 3))
```

using quote within syntax quote is actually a useful trick for writing macros that deliberatly intoduce new symbols into the scope of the caller, which is called **symbol capture**.